How can we color a study in tradingview widget?
i create tradingview widget and studies in javascript.
i tried this structure and it works.
    "studies_overrides": {
        "moving average.ma.color": "#FF0000",
        "moving average.ma.linewidth": 2,
    }

yes, it works for all of them. but, there are 3 moving averages on graph and i need to change first one's color and line width.
i couldn't find any solution, either documentation or stackoverflow.
i really need your opinions.
thanks in advance.
